# Set bash script in Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a bash script `.sh` which needs to be executed as a **Target Simulator** in Eclipse. The problem is, if I run the script with `sh run.sh` command in terminal, it throws **Bad Substitution** error. But it works perfectly with `bash run.sh`. Apparently, Eclipse run it with sh command cause it gives the same error in console. But how can I make Eclipse to run the script with bash instead?

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10.

[image: Shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` and `sh` aren't the same shell. There are many constructs valid in `bash` that are not understood by `sh`.

Have you provided a correct *sheebang* as the first line of your script?

```
#!/bin/bash
```

---

If so -- and if Eclipse insist on running script with `sh`, you still have the option of wrap your script in a *heredoc* and pass it to bash explicitly:

```
sh$ cat run.sh
bash << EOF

#
# Here is your bash script 
#

EOF
```

This is mostly a hack until you find *how* to instruct Eclipse of using the *right* shell. I'm sure there is a way!

Comment: @MikaelS. Have you tried to wrap the script in a _heredoc_ ? BTW could you provide some link(s) corresponding the the "Eclipse Target Simulator". I'm not quite sure to understand which part of Eclipse it is.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that ASAP. The Target Simulator is part of the debug configuration when you develop Eclipse plug-ins.

Comment: @MikaelS. 'Target Simulator' is not part of the standard Eclipse plug-in development tools.

Comment: @greg-449, you are right. It's probably part of this specific plugin that I'm struggling with now.